# VBA code for Multiple inputs search comparison

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I need to search from a data in excel using a macro

[image: IMG:]

If for example above image is a default list and if i gave a input using a input box.

- Case:1
  If input as "a1,a2,b1,c4"
  it should reflect "All data is correct"
- Case:2
  If input is "a1,a2,b5,c5,c4"
  It should reflect " Error: b5 & c5 are not available" & should run the loop again till it becomes a perfect match (like in case1)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. You mention "b5 & b6 are not available" but the input string doesn't contain b6. Should it? Are you simply trying to search a list to see if each entered value is present? Please edit your post to clarify.

Comment: My bad, it is c5 instead of b6. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. It asks for the titles input, then check if there are correct. If some are not correct, a message box shows the incorrect tiles. Then, an input box is shown again to enter titles. If the titles are correct, then a message box is displayed, nd the loop is exited.

```
Sub FindTitles()


    Dim blnCorrect, blnFound As Boolean
    Dim myarray
    Dim myinput, notitle As String
    Dim lRow, mybound As Long
    
    'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Loop while entered values are incorrect
    Do While blnCorrect = False
        'Get the titles
        myinput = InputBox("Enter titles", "Titles")
        myarray = Split(myinput, ",")
        mybound = UBound(myarray) - LBound(myarray) + 1
    
        notitle = ""
        'Loop through the entered titles
        For x = 0 To mybound - 1
            'Loop through the titles on the worksheet
            For Each mycells In Range("A2:A" & lRow)
                'If title is found, exit the loop
                If mycells.Value = myarray(x) Then
                    blnFound = True
                    Exit For
                Else
                    blnFound = False
                End If
                            
            Next
    
            If Not blnFound Then
                'Append the title not found
                notitle = notitle & myarray(x) & " & "
            End If
    
        Next
    
        If notitle = "" Then
       
            MsgBox Prompt:="All titles are available", Title:="Title(s) found"
            'Set blnCorrect to True to exit the loop
            blnCorrect = True
        Else
            notitle = Left(notitle, (Len(notitle) - 3))
            MsgBox Prompt:= " Error: " & notitle & " are not available", Title:="Title(s) not found"
        End If
    
    Loop

End Sub
```